# Does locking have an overhead if there are no concurrent usages of the lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, locking

Consider this:

```
lock (lock1)
{
    lock (lock2)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Does `lock2` have an impact (overhead) here?

Comment: Uncontested locks are cheap. From your snippet, it's impossible to say whether `lock2` is going to be contested or not

Comment: This is a bit irrelevant to the question at hand but if you have nested locks like this, make **absolutely sure** you always lock them in the same order. If by any chance a thread gains lock2 and then tries to get lock1 while another thread already holds it and is waiting on lock2 you got yourself a deadlock.

Comment: Acc. to [these](http://kynosarges.org/LockPerformance.html) performance tests even uncontested locks _"can still double the execution time of a small non-trivial algorithm"_

Comment: This is a great question. Too bad it was closed by some trigger happy moderator. I'd love to see a thoughtful answer but I guess that's not possible now.

Comment: @Olivier: Well, he got another chance to provide it

Comment: @canton7 Why is it not possible to determine that? (assuming this is the only piece of code obviously)

Comment: @Yahav I can't say how many threads are attempting to acquire `lock2` at the same time, or how long it's held for. You've literally provided nothing other than an indication that some thread, somewhere, is holding a lock for some period of time, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is always an overhead when entering a lock. But the cost is quite small, roughly 10-50ns if there is no contention (depending on the system).